# HTML CSS Validation Error

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

```
Error found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!
```

i have my site [here][link removed]

but im failing to validate either online or in dreamweaver cs5.

the problem being:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

what should i change this to, then?

im beginning to learn HTML, CSS so forgive me if my situation is naive.

thank you for your input/help.

*the site only works in IE8 and Chrome!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the following in your source code:

`<title>God&copy</title>`

to

`<title>God&copy;</title>`

(html entities must be terminated with a semicolon)

and change

`<script language="javascript" src="script/sitescript.js"></script>`

to

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/sitescript.js"></script>`

(the `<script>` tag requires the `type` attribute)

Comment: yep that fixed it (online validation). but in dreamweaver it is still giving the same error. any ideas?

Comment: I don't bother with Dreamweaver. Ever. The W3C is the only thing you should really be concerned with.